# How can I read values from all the redis end points connected using 'services.AddDistributedRedisCache'?

Tags: .net-core, redis

How can I read values in a .NET Core application from all the Redis end points connected using 'services.AddDistributedRedisCache'?

Scenario:

1. Application is connected with two redis end points Master and Slave where slave is configured for read and write.

   services.AddDistributedRedisCache(o =>
   {
   o.Configuration = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Redis-MasterHost:Port,Redis-SlaveHost:Port");
   });
2. In case, if application is not able to connect to master, it is getting connected to slave and all next write operations are performed on slave. These values are written only on slave(not present on master).
3. Now when application is able to connect to master again, all read operations are performed only on master and thus not able to get values present only on slave.

Is there any way to read value from both master and slave at a time?